ArcGIS API for Python - determine if feature service was published from ArcGIS Pro?
We publish most of our ArcGIS Online (AGOL) content from ArcGIS Pro, with the original data stored in local file Geodatabases.  However, we have some layers that exist only in AGOL (eg, Survey123 layers) and we want to back these up locally.
I currently have a ArcGIS API for Python script that will back up all of our AGOl feature service layers.  However, doing this for the layers that are just copies of local data is redundant, as these layers already get backed up locally, anyhow.
Is there any way (using the ArcGIS API for Python) that I can determine if an AGOL feature service was published from ArcGIS Pro?
I can print the 'properties' of an 'item' of type 'Feature Service', but I can't see anything in those properties that might help with this.
UPDATE:
I think I've actually caught myself out with a X/Y problem here.  The issue is not really whether they feature service was published from Pro or not, it is whether AGOL is the master data source or not.  In theory, I might originally publish something from Pro, and then the AGOL version becomes the master data, and the local data removed.
So now that I've understood my problem better, I think I've figured out the correct way forward.  I'll post an answer.

As per the 'update' edited into the original question, I think I've actually caught myself out with a X/Y problem here (see that post for why I think this is the case).
So my solution now is to create a 'No Backup' group in AGOL, and to manually add each item that should not be backed up to this group.
There is no automatic way to determine which items should be backed up without some manual intervention, and I figured that a group was as good a way as any to 'tag' these items for exclusion from backup.
I'm trialling this today, and it appears to be working ok.

Is your end goal to backup only the survey 123 layers locally? If yes, you can use python API to loop through and export individual survey 123 folders created for each survey forms respectively in you AGOL folders list.
https://developers.arcgis.com/survey123/guide/export-survey-data-with-attachments/

It's not just Survey123 though, unfortunately.  It's any feature services (layers) for which the master data is not already stored locally.  Ie, any feature service for which AGOL is the master data source.
